# Play Store - Ionic app suddenly incompatible after adding Camera2 API plugin

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I have an Ionic app and when I was about to publish my new version with a new plugin that I developed based on Camera2 API, Play Store say it is incompatible with all 6069 devices (phones) it was compatible with before.

Those are the features I added to `AndroidManifest.xml` that they mention no devices are compatible with:

- android.hardware.camera2.autofocus
- android.hardware.camera2.full
- android.hardware.camera

I thought most, if not all, devices would support those features.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful to exactly match the feature names, since if you misspell something, you won't match with any device (since no device reports supporting that misspelled feature).

Specifically, there's no `android.hardware.camera2.autofocus` or `android.hardware.camera2.full` in the [PackageManager feature list](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#FEATURE_CAMERA_AUTOFOCUS).  You probably want `android.hardware.camera.autofocus` and `android.hardware.camera.level.full`.